# Key Error "None of [Int64Index([ 53, 0,\n 0],\n dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, integer

```
Unique['DiffTimeMinutes'] = Unique['DiffTimeMinutes'].fillna(0).astype(int)

if Unique[Unique['DiffTimeMinutes']]>30:
    display(Unique)
```

this is my code and it give me error like this

```
Key Error "None of [Int64Index([  53,   0,\n               0],\n           dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

Cant able to find it anywhere

```
if Unique[Unique['DiffTimeMinutes']]>30:
    display(Unique)

Unique['DiffTimeMinutes'] = Unique['DiffTimeMinutes'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to do: `display(Unique[Unique['DiffTimeMinutes']>30])`?